# Passing expression not result to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

I use great library [angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt). Under the hood it creates `input`. I want to translate this input placeholder.

In my app I use [anular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) for translation. This library uses `translate` filter. For regular placeholder I can just use

```
<input placeholder="{{MY-KEY | translate}}">
```

But here I have directive that takes attributes and pass then to `input`.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
              placeholder="{{MY-KEY | translate}}"/>
```

So I need to pass expression not its result as I need ability to change language time to time and each time translate filter will be called

How can I pass a such value?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Show us the code of your directive.

Comment: It is not my directive it is <angucomplete-alt>, I'll update my question

Comment: What's the reason to 'pass expression not its result' here?

Comment: because of I need ability to change language time to time and each time translate filter will be called

Comment: It shouldn't be done like that. You're asking how to reach potential solution (which is incorrect btw). It is an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angucomplete-alt` (as well as any other sensible directive) uses data bindings to translate attributes to child element. This means that interpolated `"{{MY-KEY | translate}}"` value will be assigned to `input`'s placeholder attribute every time `MY-KEY` changes. It will surely won't work if the behaviour `translate` filter was changed but `MY-KEY` wasn't.

After the language for `translate` filter had been switched, do `$rootScope.$apply()`.